# Namespacing a Backbone app using require js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, namespaces, requirejs, js-amd

I'm trying to create a namespace for my backbone app so I can make calls globally.

Normally, I'd just do it like this:

```
var myNamespace = window.myNamespace || {};
myNamespace.SomeView = Backbone.View.extend(..);
```

Not sure how to achieve this using require js

Comment: Here's a good resources for getting started with requirejs and backbone: http://backbonetutorials.com/organizing-backbone-using-modules/

Comment: I updated the code example with more comments

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do the same in your `require` or `define` calls, `window`'s still there (if you work in browsers).

```
// views/app.js
define(['router', 'views/main-view'], function (router, mainView) {
  var App = function () { /* main app module */ };
  // do your "global" export
  window.App = App;
  return App;
});

// views/header-view.js
define(['views/app', 'models/user'], function (App, User) {
  // your header view code here
  // note that you have access to `App` already in a closure
  // but you can still talk to it by doing
  globalAppReference = window.App;
  globalAppReference === App; // true
});
```

The question is why would you need it? Ideally all your modules would be defined with requireJS, so you don't need to refer to them through global object.

Comment: I agree with @gryzzly. A global variable (namespace is a euphemism) is the old way to do it. RequireJS modules are the new way. You don't need or want both. Just use requirejs modules.

Comment: Thanks Everyone! This has been really helpful.